# How to loop through array of numbers and match them with array of objects with same id

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

```
arr1:[1,4,5]
arr2:[
        { id: 1, title:'title', body:'body'},
        { id: 2, title:'title', body:'body'},
        { id: 3, title:'title', body:'body'},
        { id: 4, title:'title', body:'body'},
        { id: 5, title:'title', body:'body'},
        { id: 6, title:'title', body:'body'},
     ]
```

In React, I'm trying to grab the whole object of `arr2` if the number from `arr1` matches the ID of the object in `arr2`.

So from this example I am trying to get each object from `arr2` with ID (1,4,5)

Comment: Can you post your attempt please?

Comment: Try to find how to filter array items by object attribute?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to filter arr2 matching its ids.

```js
  const arr1 = [1, 4, 5];
  const arr2 = [
    { id: 1, title: "title", body: "body" },
    { id: 2, title: "title", body: "body" },
    { id: 3, title: "title", body: "body" },
    { id: 4, title: "title", body: "body" },
    { id: 5, title: "title", body: "body" },
    { id: 6, title: "title", body: "body" }
  ];

  const result = arr2.filter(item => arr1.includes(item.id));

  console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. Much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Simple, filter through the data with the matching id from `arr1`

```js
const arr1 =[1,4,5]
const arr2 =[
        { id: 1, title:'title', body:'body'},
        { id: 2, title:'title', body:'body'},
        { id: 3, title:'title', body:'body'},
        { id: 4, title:'title', body:'body'},
        { id: 5, title:'title', body:'body'},
        { id: 6, title:'title', body:'body'},
];

function findMatchData(sourceData, match) { 
  return sourceData.filter((current) => {
    return match.includes(current.id)
  });
}

console.log(findMatchData(arr2, arr1))
```

I hope this helps you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function `Array.prototype.filter()` along with the function `Array.prototype.includes` in order to filter the desired objects by `id`.

```js
let arr1 = [1,4,5],
    arr2 = [{ id: 1, title:'title', body:'body'},{ id: 2, title:'title', body:'body'},{ id: 3, title:'title', body:'body'},{ id: 4, title:'title', body:'body'},{ id: 5, title:'title', body:'body'},{ id: 6, title:'title', body:'body'}],
    result = arr2.filter(({id}) => arr1.includes(id));
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Let me include here a different solution with `reduce()` and `find()` combination.

[`Array.prototype.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce):

> The reduce() method executes a reducer function (that you provide) on each element of the array, resulting in a single output value.

[`Array.prototype.find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find):

> The find() method returns the value of the first element in the provided array that satisfies the provided testing function.

Try the following:

```js
const arr1 = [1,4,5];
const arr2 = [
  { id: 1, title:'title', body:'body'},
  { id: 2, title:'title', body:'body'},
  { id: 3, title:'title', body:'body'},
  { id: 4, title:'title', body:'body'},
  { id: 5, title:'title', body:'body'},
  { id: 6, title:'title', body:'body'},
];

const result = arr2.reduce((a, {id,body}) => {
  if (arr1.find(e => id === e)) a.push({id, body});
  return a;
}, []);

console.log(result);
```

I hope that helps!